# LibGdx Project Runs on desktop but not on Android simulator

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I recently started learning LibGdx I made a splash screen. It runs on desktop quite fine but when i try to run on android emulator/simulator or android mobile it doesn't runs. It shows a black screen only. Please help me over this. I've attached the link to project in this query.

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B38mBPsRVO3ScU83M1dXblItS00/edit?usp=sharing

i am adding code here
Android Applications

```
AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
cfg.useGL20 = true;
```

Main LibGdx Project Code

```
public void show() {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    Texture splashTexture = new Texture("image/splash.PNG");
    splash = new Sprite(splashTexture);
    splash.setSize(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

}

public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.begin();
    splash.draw(batch);
    batch.end();
}
```

Its the simple splash screen code. I did research on net but didn't find anything useful with this. Please Help me over this.

Comment: thats a wrong practice man to give proper complete code someone will use it and u even wont know it

Comment: I'll take care of it from now. I've added code here please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
public void show() {
 manaer=new AssetManager();
    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    manager.load("Image/splash.PNG",Texture.class);
    manager.finishLoading();
    Texture splashTexture = manager.get("Image/splash.PNG",Texture.class);
    splash = new Sprite(splashTexture);
    splash.setSize(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

}
```

Thing is ur assets is not completely loaded before it is drawn.  so using manager.finishloading() u compel  the code to stop execution till image gets loaded

Comment: also make sure to change path to Image not image

Comment: Thank you Sir. Its working. Thanks for your help. Now i just need to get it horizontal. Thank you very much for help sir.

Comment: for horizontal u need to change in ur manifest file in android project  orientation to potrait instead of landscape. i guess u have figured it out by now :-)

Comment: Sir I was knowing the thing for portrait mode was confused where to do it then i figured it out it was in manifest. Thank you for your help Sir.

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm not going to download a random RAR, and you didn't post code, I am going to make an educated guess.

Possible problems:

- Your device doesn't support OpenGL ES 2, or not completely. I've seen devices support 2 but still require power-of-two sizes for textures (Droid 1, for example). Try padding out your textures to a size that is the power of 2.
- You aren't even trying to use OpenGL ES 2. In your main activity, make sure you have something similar to the following:

  ```
  AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
  cfg.useGL20 = true;
  ```

You are far more likely to get a targeted answer if you post source and don't ask folks to make downloads.

Comment: Sir I've added the code and I was using Power of 2 Texture and the code snippet  you provided. But it wasn't working and i'll take care of giving my code here in text for the problem. Thanks for replying and guiding me.